# how to run one docker per instance to use elb

Tags: amazon-web-services

1. I am trying to use ecs from aws and i have 3 instances in my ecs
   cluster
2. I have these 3 instances as part of auto scaling group.
3. I want only one docker of  each image type to run on one instance so
   i can use aws elb.I am usign below approach for this.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/category/ec2-container-service/

4. Now if my instance per say instance 1  goes down lets say my desired
   count is 3 for my service.It will try to start my api-image docker
    in  instance 2 to meet desired count and  now i have 2 docker of my
    api-docker  running  in same instance .Hence i cannot use aws
   elb?Is there any  way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the ECS scheduler doesn't work due to port conflicting if you have 2 services in the same host. You have to turn on the instance 1 anyway ( if you persist using ELB)